# MySQL: ERROR 1064 (42000) - Why is ORDER BY failing?

Tags: sql, mysql

```
as a 
limit 0,50 
ORDER BY SortOrder, paid desc, ae desc, name asc, title asc
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY SortOrder, paid desc, ae desc, name asc, titile asc' at line 48

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to change the order of the parts of your query. Change it to

```
as a ORDER BY SortOrder, paid desc, ae desc, name asc, title asc limit 0,50
```

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, `LIMIT` needs to be at the end of the statement.